# Transitive property for uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n,f,g_{m,n}$ and $g_m$ be real valued functions where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Suppose that as $n\to\infty$:

- $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly.
- $g_{m,n}$ converges to $g_m$ uniformly.

Also suppose that as $m\to\infty$:

- $g_{m,n}$ converges to $f_n$ uniformly.

**My question**: Does $g_{m}$ converge to $f$ uniformly as $m\to\infty$?

**Edit**: Using @TonyS.F.'s suggestion. From the triangle inequality
$$
\|f - g_m\|_\infty \leq \|f - f_n\|_\infty + \|f_n - g_{m.n}\|_\infty + \|g_{m.n} - g_m\|_\infty
$$
for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty} \|f - g_m\|_\infty \leq \lim_{m\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \|f - f_n\|_\infty + \|f_n - g_{m.n}\|_\infty + \|g_{m.n} - g_m\|_\infty
$$
and so $g_m$ converges to $f$ uniformly. QED.

Comment: You have to provide the full context of this exercise . It seems lik there is something missing

Comment: It's true, just the take the limit w.r.t $n$ after you've taken it w.r.t. $m$

Comment: @TonyS.F. can you elaborate answer for that?